# Using 'filter' option in backbone.js paginator requestPager

Tags: javascript, filter, backbone.js, paginator

I currently have a working backbone.js requestPager collection, but would like to use the filter option.  I am currently struggling with how to make it work.  It works when I just use something link "'filter': 'sam'" in the server_api function, but I can't seem to get this work dynamically.

I think where I'm running into issues is with how to setup the view to update the collection.  With clientPager there is a this.collection.setFilter() function, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for requestPager.

Can anyone point me to simple example of result filtering with the requestPager?

Comment: Could you please post some code that is relevant to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your app design. At a simple case, you could write something like this:

```
var PaginatedCollection = Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.extend({  
    setFilter: function (filter) {
        this.server_api['$filter'] = filter;
        this.currentPage = 0;
        this.fetch();
    },
    // ... 

});
```

Comment: Yes, I did something similar.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I did this similar to user1248256, and thought I'd post as well.

Here's the relevant code from the collection:

```
server_api: {
    'filter': function() {return this.filterString },
    'limit': function() { return this.perPage },
    'offset': function() { return this.currentPage},
},
setFilter: function (filter) {
    this.filterString = filter; 
    this.pager();
}
```